# Creating a Buy Limit gives invalid price error

Tags: mql5

I am trying to write an Expert Advisor with MQL5 that initiates buy limits based on certain EMA values. Here is the code that I have written in OnTick() function.

```
        MqlRates priceData[]; //create a price array

       //sort the array from the current candle downwards
       ArraySetAsSeries(priceData, true);

       //copy candle prices for 5 candles into array
       CopyRates(_Symbol, _Period, 0,5, priceData);

       //EMA Based Trading

       int ema8 = iMA(_Symbol, _Period, 8, 0, MODE_EMA, PRICE_CLOSE);
       int ema21 = iMA(_Symbol, _Period, 21, 0, MODE_EMA, PRICE_CLOSE);

       //Arrays to store EMAs
       double ema8Array[], ema21Array[];


       //Sorting EMAs fot the current candle downwards 
       ArraySetAsSeries(ema8Array, true);
       ArraySetAsSeries(ema21Array, true);

       //Defined EMA8, one line, current candle, 5 candles, store result
       CopyBuffer(ema8,0,0,5,ema8Array);

       //Defined EMA21, one line, current candle, 5 candles, store result
       CopyBuffer(ema21,0,0,5,ema21Array);

       if(ema8Array[0] > ema21Array[0])
       {

          if(
          (ema8Array[0] >= priceData[1].close) 
          && 
          (priceData[1].close < ema21Array[0]))
          {
            Print("Chance To Buy"); 

            double closePrices[5];

            closePrices[0]=priceData[1].close;
            closePrices[1]=priceData[2].close;
            closePrices[2]=priceData[3].close;
            closePrices[3]=priceData[4].close;

            if((OrdersTotal() == 0) && (PositionsTotal() == 0))
            {
             int maxValue=ArrayMaximum(closePrices,0,WHOLE_ARRAY);
             double buyStop=closePrices[maxValue]+0.00003;
             double stopLoss=priceData[1].close-0.00004;
             double takeProfit=buyStop+(buyStop-stopLoss);

             trade.BuyLimit(0.01,buyStop,_Symbol,0,0,ORDER_TIME_GTC,0,"Limit Added");
            }
          }


   }
```

When I run it it strategy testing with EURUSD on H1 timeline, I get the following error most of the times:

```
2018.12.25 14:27:47.117 2017.01.02 09:00:09   failed buy limit 0.01 EURUSD at 1.05342 [Invalid price]
2018.12.25 14:27:47.117 2017.01.02 09:00:09   CTrade::OrderSend: buy limit 0.01 EURUSD at 1.05342 [invalid price]
```

Can you please tell me what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure your buy limit price 1.05342 is valid? It might happen that the obtained price is above the current bid so you cannot place buylimit there, only market. `if(SymbolInfoDouble(_Symbol,SYMBOL_ASK)>buyStop) trade.Buy(...); else trade.BuyLimit(...);`

Comment: @DanielKniaz Thank you for your response. You are right, error occurs when buyStop is above the current bid price. e.g. current bid price is 1.5240 and I want to place a future buy order if price reaches 1.05342. So, isn't BuyLimit() function used for this scenario?

Comment: There is a concept of better price and worse price. if you wished to buy at 101 and find out it is 100 now - price is better. vice a verse for sell. Limit orders are to allow execution at a better price, stop orders (buystop, sell stop) are for execution at a worse price. Technically it is be possible to place limit orders at current(exchange) or better price(fx broker). If you use `<Trade\Trade.mqh>` for managing trades, it has `BuyStop(...)` and `SellStop(...)` methods